# Question about sliced arrays overriding dictionary assignment in python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have the following code. I'm trying to add the numpy array EPtmp (filled with zeros for CH4, filled with ones for NO) to the dictionary, with keys 'CH4' and 'NO'. On the first iteration of the for loop, the zero array is correctly associated with key CH4. On the second iteration, the ones array overwrites the entries for both the previously written CH4 key as well as the new NO key. If I remove the slice from EPtmp[:] = EP so that it is instead EPtmp = EP, it works perfectly without overwriting the previously written arrays. This seems like it has something to do with the way that Python allocates or accesses memory, but I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation to explain this behavior yet. Any ideas why the slice [:] causes the dictionary overwrite?

```
  import numpy as np
  species_names = ['O2', 'CH4', 'NO', 'N2', 'O', 'CH3', 'H', 'HO2', 'N2O',     'NO2', 'NNH']
  target_index_species = [1,2]
  EP_spec_dict = {}
  EPtmp = np.zeros(len(species_names),'d')

  for index_target_local, index_target_global in enumerate(target_index_species):
     EP = np.ones(len(species_names))*index_target_local 
     EPtmp[:] = EP
     print("Going to add",species_names[index_target_global],"EP tmp",EPtmp)
     EP_spec_dict[species_names[index_target_global]] = EPtmp
     print("Full dict",EP_spec_dict)
```

Comment: You have exactly one assignment to `EPtmp`, and it's outside the loop: therefore there is exactly one array.  You add references to this one array to your dictionary multiple times.  All of those references will necessarily show the same value, that which was most recently stored in the array.

Comment: So EP is updated each time within the loop... I thought that by using the slice for EPtmp I'd be taking the values of EP instead of the reference to EP? I also found that if I update the dictionary with a slice like: 
    EP_spec_dict[species_names[index_target_global]] = EPtmp[:]
the behavior still persists.

Comment: You're creating a brand new `EP` on each iteration, so it doesn't matter whether you copy or reference it.  The problem is that you were copying it by stuffing it into the existing `EPtmp`, thus overwriting the previous contents.

Answer (score 1):

`EPtmp = EP` makes EPtmp a reference to EP which means if you change EPtmp you're actually changing EP because they are the same array.

`EPtmp[:]` = EP makes a copy of EP so changing EPtmp will not change EP.

Try the following in your console:

```
a=[1,2]

b=[0,0]

a=b

a[0]=5

b
Out[13]: [5, 0]
```

and

```
a=[1,2]

b=[0,0]

a[:]=b

a[0]=5

b
Out[18]: [0, 0]
```

But slicing also works the other way around. If you have `b = a` and then set a by doing a = [], b isn't changed because you're creating a new a. However, if you don't create a new a but explicitly overwrite the old one by `a[:]=[]`, b changes.

Try:

```
a=[1,2]

b=a

c=b

a=[1,3] #doesn't change b and c

b[:]=[1,4] #changes c
```

Basically, a=b means a is a pointer to where b points in the memory and a[:]=b means write the content of b where a points to.

So in your example your dicitonary contains a pointer to EPtmp. By `EP_spec_dict[species_names[index_target_global]] = EPtmp`

Now if you make a new EPtmp with `EPtmp=EP`, that's in a different memory section and `EP_spec_dict[species_names[index_target_global]]` still points to the old EPtmp's memory section. However with EPtmp[:]=EP you're just overwriting the memory content of EPtmp and not making a new one.

Comment: I'm aware of the slicing behavior that you mentioned; my comment is actually about the reverse problem - when I use slices like in the case I showed, it actually updates all previous entries made to the base dictionary. Given the typical behavior like in the examples you showed, I'd expect the opposite.

Comment: Thanks, the last few sentences made a lot of sense!

Comment: @user2950933 I also included what that specifically means for your example, does that solve your question or is something still unclear?